# Getting error on sending ether/wei in payable function

Tags: solidity, remix, dapps, error, payable

error:
transact to CampaignFactory.createCampaign errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information.

code:

```
 function createCampaign(uint deposit, address ll) public payable{
   // dpst = deposit;
    require(msg.value > (40*deposit)/100 wei);
    address newCampaign = address((new Campaign).value(msg.value)(deposit, ll, token_address, 1));
    token_instance.setAllowance(deposit, token_holder, newCampaign);

    deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);


}
```

Campaign constructor declaration:

```
    constructor (uint depositInWei, address ll, address addressOfTokenUsed, uint weiCostOfEachToken) public payable{
```

Comment: Comment out `require` statements until you find out which one causes the problem. The text about "payable constructor" is just a guess and usually you can ignore that part.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I already tried removing require statement. Although not able to send ether/wei to the createCampaign function.

Comment: Well then just remove code lines and see which one causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not have token address, ABI or setAllowance functions, I have removed them and it worked perfectly. The problem is raised due to setAllowance function. I shared code below, you can test it on Remix IDE.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract CampaignFactory{

address [] deployedCampaigns;
function createCampaign(uint deposit, address ll) public payable{
    require(msg.value > (40*deposit)/100 wei);
    address newCampaign = address((new Campaign).value(msg.value)(deposit, ll, 1));

    deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    } 

}
contract Campaign {
    constructor (uint depositInWei, address ll, uint weiCostOfEachToken) public payable{
    }

}
```

Hope it helps,